# How to avoid this with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table, and in the first `td` I have a glyphicon:

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></td>
```

I added a onclick event on it, which will toggle the class, but when I do:

[image]

As you can see, I can accidentally "select" extra areas. That looks really bad.

Is there any suggestion on it?

Comment: There is an answer to that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting).

Comment: Beat you to it @Octopus

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the user selection.

```
.glyphicon{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your element, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting):

```
.ClassName,
.ClassName:focus {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    outline-style:none;/*IE*/
}
```

Comment: Very good point, flagged now